# How to scrape a password protected website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm having difficulties scraping a password protected website. I know there are plenty of questions out there, however, none of them solved my problem.

The problem is, I don't know what the problem is. I do get a `200` response from their server, however, it is not the content I'm expecting. It's indeed a big HTML structure, but there are words like "access", "RequestURLDenied", "Password", "Help", "Sign in", which indicates my login attempt did not work properly. I don't know what to change though? Does someone have experience with scraping?

This is my code so far (extracted from [here](https://github.com/kazuar/login_scraper_example)):

```
import requests
from lxml import html

USERNAME = "XXX"
PASSWORD = "XXX"
LOGIN_URL = "https://signin.lexisnexis.com/lnaccess/app/signin?back=https%3A%2F%2Fadvance.lexis.com%3A443%2Fnexis-uni%2Flaapi%2Fpermalink%2F35a8b8d7-925d-4219-b89d-af27c10a7a31%2F%3Fcontext%3D1516831&aci=nu"
LOGIN_URL2 = "https://signin.lexisnexis.com:443/lnaccess/Transition?aci=nu"
URL = "https://advance.lexis.com/api/document?collection=news&id=urn:contentItem:7XM6-WXH0-Y9M6-H1V0-00000-00&context=1516831"

def main():
    # Create session
    session = requests.session()

    # Get login cookies
    session.get(LOGIN_URL)

    # Create payload - used to log into password protected area
    login_data = {
        "rmtoken": "dummy", 
        "request_id": "null", 
        "OAM_REQ": "null", 
        "userid": USERNAME,
        "password": PASSWORD,  
        "rmflag": "0", 
        "aci": "nu"
    }

    # Perform login
    session.post(LOGIN_URL, data = login_data)

    # Scrape url
    result = session.get(URL)

    # Content
    print(result.content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is what the response looks like when I run the script:

[image: script output]

Another question: Say I get to the point where I can login from code and I perform a couple of thousand server requests to extract text, could this cause problems with their server :D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All in all your code looks correct you just made a few mistakes with the URL you are sending the POST request to and you're using an incomplete payload.

Try the following code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from lxml.etree import tostring

USERNAME = "XXX"
PASSWORD = "XXX"
LOGIN_URL = "https://signin.lexisnexis.com/lnaccess/app/signin?back=https%3A%2F%2Fadvance.lexis.com%3A443%2Fnexis-uni%2Flaapi%2Fpermalink%2F35a8b8d7-925d-4219-b89d-af27c10a7a31%2F%3Fcontext%3D1516831&aci=nu"
URL = "https://advance.lexis.com/api/document?collection=news&id=urn:contentItem:7XM6-WXH0-Y9M6-H1V0-00000-00&context=1516831"

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    # Get login cookies
    session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)

    # Create payload - used to log into password protected are
    payload = {
        "rmtoken": "dummy", 
        "request_id": "null", 
        "OAM_REQ": "null", 
        "userid": USERNAME,
        "password": PASSWORD,  
        "rmflag": "0", 
        "aci": "nu"
    }

    # Perform login
    result = session_requests.post("https://signin.lexisnexis.com:443/lnaccess/Transition?aci=nu", data = payload)

    # Scrape url
    result = session_requests.get(URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
    # bucket_names = tree.xpath("//div[@class='repo-list--repo']/a/text()")

    print(tostring(tree))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I did adapt some of your changes, however, your login url returns error code 500. It's still not working :(. But yeah, I saw that there were more values, I just wasn't sure what to do with it. I updated my code.

Comment: Also, how did you find out the url for the post request and are you sure it is correct?

Comment: I'm very sure, I got it using Burp Suite

Comment: As I don't have an account on this website I can't really tell you at this point what is going wrong

Comment: When I try to connect to the url in R this happens: `> test_session <- html_session("https://signin.lexisnexis.com:443/lnaccess/Transition?aci=nu")
Warning message:
In request_GET(session, url) : Internal Server Error (HTTP 500).`. Not sure if it is correct. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: You can only send POST requests to this URL